# Why this flag was declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I'd like kindly ask, why this flag about not an answer was declined?
The answer is [Indirectly referenced from required .class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115971/indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-file/27838542#27838542) the reason for decline was " declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

The question was about missing WebLogic class `weblogic.utils.expressions.ExpressionMap`. The provided answer was about completely different class from WebSphere `com.ibm.portal.state.exceptions.StateException`.

I wouldn't complain, if the answer was general and would explain that you would need to add server runtime to your classpath.  But providing answer with details about WebSphere Portal for someone who asks about WebLogic is completely useless for him and its just answer to a different issue but not this.

So, please could someone explain me, why the flag was declined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Not an Answer" are for answers like this:

> I Like Waffles

Or

> Check out this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283507/1783619)

Or

> Thanks! But I have this other question

Answers that are just plain *wrong* are still answers. Downvote, but please do not flag.

Comment: Off-topic, waffles are amazing. They just don't belong in Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that answers, useless in the context of the question are also not-an-answer.

Comment: @Gas The issue is that we can't rely on moderators (or reviewers) to have the domain knowledge to make that judgement call. Thus we ask that you just downvote