# NAA flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

According to the accepted answer on this question [Why this flag was declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283507/why-this-flag-was-declined) the NAA flag can be used on a link only answer. What if the answer has two links and merely the statement

> There is a detailed description of the trigger debugging process in
>   the documentation: Debugging \ Debugging Stored Routines \ How To:
>   Start Trigger Debugging.

I first flagged this as an NAA that was declined, and I then flagged for moderator intervention, primarily because I was wondering if I had mis-flagged, but also mentioning that the linked site appears to belong to the person posting the answer. The moderator had also declined it but the only reason given was that there was no evidence to support it. But as I see it the evidence is right before our eyes.

I am not linking to the answer in question to avoid the meta effect, but it's hoped that a mod sees this and explains what's happening.

Comment: A single flag by a single user just isn't good enough to destroy an accepted answer that has been vetted by over 9,000 programmers and never once downvoted.  Should be a bit obvious.  If you don't like the answer then do what you can do yourself, you can edit it, you can DV it, you can post a better answer.

Comment: The last VLQ flag that was declined on your account was on Dec 10th. Is that the one which you're asking about?

Comment: @BhargavRao sorry original flag was not an answer. Second time I flagged it bringing it to moderator attention.

Comment: Why would you re-flag something with a different flag just because the first one didn't stick?

Comment: @ivarni because I have read here in meta before that that is he thing to do

Comment: BTW, @BhargavRao I seem to have just been serially upvoted but I think the two votes on http://stackoverflow.com/a/41362265/267540 are legit.

Comment: @e4c5 Don't worry bout those, The serial voting script will take care. If it's not reversed even after 2 days, Then use the /contact page and tell the devs, They'll take care of it :)

Comment: @BhargavRao oky doky thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I understand that you didn't link to the answer in an effort to avoid the Meta effect, and while that's totally fine, your representation of said answer appears to be rather disingenuous.
Here's the full text of the actual answer:

> You can [debug triggers](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) using [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Try trial version.
>
> There is a detailed description of the trigger debugging process in the documentation: Debugging \ Debugging Stored Routines \ How To: Start Trigger Debugging.

(Yes, it was edited, but the edit was back in January of 2012, so that couldn't have been done after you flagged it. This is the form in which you saw and evaluated it.)

From my perspective, this is very obviously *not* a link-only answer. If you cannot see that, please stop flagging until you can.

There are two links here, but the link text is descriptive and would be valuable even if the linked pages became inaccessible. There is also a bunch of *other* text here that constitutes an answer.

In fact, the only thing that would make this answer *better* would be (ironically) adding another link, specifically a link to the documentation referenced by the second paragraph. A pull quote from the relevant section of the documentation would also be nice, but optional.

Since you have full edit privileges, and presumably knowledge about this topic considering you hold a tag badge in [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), you could have edited these improvements into the answer, instead of flagging it. While there is no reason to invest time trying to improve low-quality posts that will never go anywhere (colloquially, albeit crudely, referred to as "polishing turds"), it should have been rather obvious that this answer does not fall into the turd category.

As [Hans Passant points out in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340282/vlq-flag-declined#comment425213_340282), this answer "has been vetted by over 9,000 programmers and never once downvoted." While not a perfect signal, that should have been a clue to you that it probably wasn't just lingering crap in need of deletion.

[Bradley's answer to the question you said you had read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283508/366904) should have been sufficient to explain why your flag was declined. The answer was neither on-face inapplicable to the question ("I like waffles"), nor was it a bare link with no other text or explanation ("Check out this [link](http://example.com)"), nor was it a question, comment, or some other non-answer. See also [Shog's infamous apple taxonomy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

While I will be the first to admit and complain about the lack of clarity surrounding the "very low quality" and "not an answer" flag thresholds, I cannot see any way in which the answer in question falls into a grey area. You could take out the links entirely, the answer would still be an answer.

If you still think the answer sucks, feel free to exercise your right to downvote it. But please don't flag it, because it would not benefit the site for it to be deleted.

Comment: you forget that this answer was placed many years ago and in those early days almost any answer got a dozen upvotes and sometimes hundreds. Even link only answers have got that many. So four upvotes is not an indication of it's quality. If you remove the links and read it again, I think you will probably start to agree with me a bit more.

Comment: *"While not a perfect signal, that should have been a clue..."* *"There are two links here, but the link text is descriptive and would be valuable even if the linked pages became inaccessible. There is also a bunch of other text here that constitutes an answer. ... You could take out the links entirely, the answer would still be an answer."*

Comment: Did you take into consideration the fact that the links are to his own site and that is frowned upon? if a 75 rep user had posted that instead of a 75k user that would have been flagged as spam by many

Comment: No, I didn't, because you didn't mention it. Your flag didn't mention it, either. How was a moderator supposed to know?

Comment: that was mentioned in the flag to moderator

Comment: I didn't mention it in the answer primarily because I was hoping to catch the eye of the moderators my question and I assume that moderators are able to go through any user's flagging history.